# Using thread pool for simulation : boost-thread and boost-asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, boost, boost-asio

I would like to use `boost::asio` to set up a thread pool.
My question is : how can I attach specific data to each of the threads created, and how can I manage individual outputs ?

To be more specific, I wrote a class `Simulation` which performs the simulation via a method taking some parameters in input.
This class contains all the data needed for the calculation.
As the data is not too big, I would like to duplicate it in order to use a different instance of the class `Simulation` in each thread of the pool.

I would like to do something like this : 
(Setting up a thread pool is explained here : [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957059/boostasio-io-service-thread-pool) and [Asio recipes](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes?skin=clean.nat,asio,pattern#A_thread_pool_for_executing_arbi))

```
class ParallelSimulation
{
  public:
    static const std::size_t N = 10;

  protected:
    std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Simulation> > simuInst; // N copy of a reference instance.

  public:

    ...

    // Simulation with a large (>>N) number of inputs
    void eval( std::vector< SimulationInput > inputs )
    {
      // Creation of the pool using N threads
      asio::io_service io_service;
      asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
      boost::thread_group threads;
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

      // Here ? Attaching the duplicates instances of class Simulation ?

      // Adding tasks
      for( std::size_t i = 0, i_end = inputs.size(); i<i_end; ++i)
        io_service.post(...); // add simulation with inputs[i] to the queue

      // How to deal with outputs ?  

      // End of the tasks
      io_service.stop();
      threads.join_all();
    }
};
```

Maybe the technique used to set up a thread pool (using `boost::asio`) is not adapted to my problem. Would you have any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the results of my research !

The distributed simulation is based on a main class `DistributedSimulation` using two implementation classes: `impl::m_io_service` and `impl::dispatcher`.

The `boost::asio` thread pool is based on attaching `io_service::run()` method to different threads. 
The idea is to redefine this method and to include a mechanism to identify the current thread. The solution below is based on thread local storage `boost::thread_specific_ptr` of `boost::uuid`. *After reading the comment of Tres, I think that identifying thread using `boost::thread::id` is a better solution (but equivalent and not too different).* 
Finally another class is used to dispatch the input data to instances of class Simulation. This class creates several instances of the same class Simulation and use them to compute the results in each thread.

```
namespace impl {

  // Create a derived class of io_service including thread specific data (a unique identifier of the thread)
  struct m_io_service : public boost::asio::io_service
  {
    static boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid> ptrSpec_;

    std::size_t run()
    {
      if(ptrSpec_.get() == 0) 
        ptrSpec_.reset(new boost::uuids::uuid(boost::uuids::random_generator()())  );

      return boost::asio::io_service::run();
    }
  };


  // Create a class that dispatches the input data over the N instances of the class Simulation
  template <class Simulation>
  class dispatcher
  {  
    public:
      static const std::size_t N = 6;

      typedef Simulation::input_t input_t;
      typedef Simulation::output_t output_t;

      friend DistributedSimulation;

    protected:
      std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Simulation> > simuInst;
      std::vector< boost::uuids::uuid >            map;

    public:

      // Constructor, creating the N instances of class Simulation
      dispatcher( const Simulation& simuRef) 
      {
        simuInst.resize(N);
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<N; ++i)
          simuInst[i].reset( simuRef.clone() );
      }

      // Record the unique identifiers and do the calculation using the right instance of class Simulation
      void dispatch( const Simulation::input_t& in  )
      {
        if( map.size() == 0 ) {
          map.push_back(*m_io_service::ptrSpec_);
          simuInst[0]->eval(in, *m_io_service::ptrSpec_);
        }    
        else {
          if( map.size() < N ) {
            map.push_back(*m_io_service::ptrSpec_);
            simuInst[map.size()-1]->eval(in, *m_io_service::ptrSpec_);
          }
          else {
            for(size_t i=0; i<N;++i) {
              if( map[i] == *m_io_service::ptrSpec_) {
                simuInst[i]->eval(in, *m_io_service::ptrSpec_);
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  };

  boost::thread_specific_ptr<boost::uuids::uuid> m_io_service::ptrSpec_;
}


  // Main class, create a distributed simulation based on a class Simulation
  template <class Simulation>
  class DistributedSimulation
  {
  public:
    static const std::size_t N = impl::dispatcher::N;

  protected: 
    impl::dispatcher _disp;

  public:
    DistributedSimulation() : _disp( Simulation() ) {}

    DistributedSimulation(Simulation& simuRef) 
    : _disp( simuRef ) {  }


    // Simulation with a large (>>N) number of inputs
    void eval( const std::vector< Simulation::input_t >& inputs, std::vector< Simulation::output_t >& outputs )
    {

      // Clear the results from a previous calculation (and stored in instances of class Simulation)
      ...

      // Creation of the pool using N threads
      impl::m_io_service io_service;
      boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
      boost::thread_group threads;
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&impl::m_io_service::run, &io_service));

      // Adding tasks
      for( std::size_t i = 0, i_end = inputs.size(); i<i_end; ++i)
        io_service.post( boost::bind(&impl::dispatcher::dispatch, &_disp, inputs[i]) );

      // End of the tasks
      io_service.stop();
      threads.join_all();

      // Gather the results iterating through instances of class simulation
      ...
    }
  };
```

---

Edit

The code below is an update of my previous solution, taking into account the comment of Tres. As I said before, it is much more readable simple !

```
  template <class Simulation>
  class DistributedSimulation
  {
    public:
      typedef typename Simulation::input_t  input_t;
      typedef typename Simulation::output_t output_t;

      typedef boost::shared_ptr<Simulation> SimulationSPtr_t;
      typedef boost::thread::id             id_t;      
      typedef std::map< id_t, std::size_t >::iterator IDMapIterator_t;

    protected: 
      unsigned int                    _NThreads;   // Number of threads
      std::vector< SimulationSPtr_t > _simuInst;   // Instances of class Simulation
      std::map< id_t, std::size_t >   _IDMap;      // Map between thread id and instance index.

    private:
      boost::mutex _mutex;

    public:

      DistributedSimulation(  ) {}

      DistributedSimulation( const Simulation& simuRef, const unsigned int NThreads = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() ) 
        { init(simuRef, NThreads); }

      DistributedSimulation(const DistributedSimulation& simuDistrib) 
        { init(simuRef, NThreads); }

      virtual ~DistributedSimulation() {}

      void init(const Simulation& simuRef, const unsigned int NThreads = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency())
      {
        _NThreads = (NThreads == 0) ? 1 : NThreads;
        _simuInst.resize(_NThreads);
        for(std::size_t i=0; i<_NThreads; ++i)
          _simuInst[i].reset( simuRef.clone() );
        _IDMap.clear();
      }


      void dispatch( const input_t& input )
      {
        // Get current thread id
        boost::thread::id id0 = boost::this_thread::get_id();

        // Get the right instance 
        Simulation* sim = NULL;        
        { 
          boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(_mutex);
          IDMapIterator_t it = _IDMap.find(id0);
          if( it != _IDMap.end() )
            sim = _simuInst[it->second].get();
        } 

        // Simulation
        if( NULL != sim )
          sim->eval(input);
      }


      // Distributed evaluation.
      void eval( const std::vector< input_t >& inputs, std::vector< output_t >& outputs )
      {
        //--Initialisation
        const std::size_t NInputs = inputs.size();

        // Clear the ouptuts f(contained in instances of class Simulation) from a previous run
        ...

        // Create thread pool and save ids
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
        boost::thread_group threads;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _NThreads; ++i)
        {
          boost::thread* thread_ptr = threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
          _IDMap[ thread_ptr->get_id() ] = i;
        }

        // Add tasks
        for( std::size_t i = 0; i < NInputs; ++i)
          io_service.post( boost::bind(&DistributedSimulation::dispatch, this, inputs[i]) );

        // Stop the service
        io_service.stop();
        threads.join_all();

        // Gather results (contained in each instances of class Simulation)
        ...
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for your application. When you make the call to `io_service.post`, you will pass in the simulation function with `inputs[i]` as the parameter. In that function (presumably a member function of `Simulation`), just store the result of the computation in the `Simulation` object, then iterate over the objects after you join the threads to collect the output.

You can pass `i` as a parameter too, if you need to identify the specific thread that did the work. This assumes that collecting the output after the simulations have completed is OK.

If you need access to the output as it's running, just have the function `post` an output task to `io_service` as needed. Be sure to protect any shared data structures with a mutex!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But I don't see how you use the N instances of the class Simulation to ensure that the thread `i` compute the results with the instance `i` (and therefore uses its own data to do the work).
The way to deal with outputs seems fine, thanks !

Comment: @gleeen.gould Can you clarify why it matters that you use thread `i` to compute the work for simulation `i`? It's possible (call `thread->get_id()` when you create it, pass that to `simulation[i]`, then have `simulation[i]`'s work function check when it gets executed that `boost::this_thread::get_id()` matches, if not return, else keep going), but I don't think it should be necessary.

Comment: Look at my solution, I hope this will clarify my objectives.